# How do you find the remainder between two Hurwitz quaternions?

Tags: quaternions

How can I do this when the multiplication between two Hurwitz quaternions can give you a non Hurwitz quaternion (eg 1+2.25i+2.5j+3.75k)?

I can do it for Lipschitz quaternions, but not when the values can be half.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You must have miscomputed, as the product of Hurwitz quaternions is also a Hurwitz quaternion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_quaternion